# Breaking up a large Java enum

Tags: java, enums

What is the recommended practice for taking a Java enum that has say 1300 values and putting it into organized groups?  I know you can't just extends the enum group, so are there other good alternatives?

Answer (score 7):

I would use an interface which these instances all share, then you can use any number of enums or load them from another data source such as a file or database.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree.  Load them from a file or the database.  However, if there are method implementations within a few of the enums, consider creating an interface, and a separate implementation for each enum that has a method defined, and then one default implementation that receives the values from the database or file.  If there are no methods defined, then simply create a POJO.

Answer (score 5):

1300 values?  Good god, who thought that was a good idea?  Did it not occur to someone after 100 that it was getting too big?

There's no good way around it that I can see.  Get a shovel and start combining them into more cohesive sub-enums.

Here's a question: How are they used?  If they are part of your application configuration, I'd recommend moving them to a database rather than keeping them in code.  They'll be more flexible that way.

Comment: They are actually in the database already.  These enums are the primary keys for a list of error codes.  Example, the 'NO_DATA_FOUND' enum key points to 'Sorry, but we are unable to locate your request' in the database.

Answer (score 5):

you can break them up like:

```
import java.util.*;
interface Children {
    Set<Enum<?>> children();
}
enum Dog implements Children {
    myDog,yourDog;
    Dog() {
        this(null);
    }
    Dog(Set<Enum<?>> children) {
        this.children=children;
    }
    @Override public Set<Enum<?>> children() {
        return children!=null?Collections.unmodifiableSet(children):null;
    }
    Set<Enum<?>> children;
}
enum Animal implements Children {
    cat,dog(EnumSet.allOf(Dog.class));
    Animal() {
        this(null);
    }
    Animal(Set children) {
        this.children=children;
    }
    @Override public Set<Enum<?>> children() {
        return children!=null?Collections.unmodifiableSet(children):null;
    }
    Set<Enum<?>> children;
}
enum Thing implements Children {
    animal(EnumSet.allOf(Animal.class)),vegetable,mineral;
    Thing() {
        this(null);
    }
    Thing(Set children) {
        this.children=children;
    }
    @Override public Set<Enum<?>> children() {
        return children!=null?Collections.unmodifiableSet(children):null;
    }
    Set<Enum<?>> children;
}
public class So8671088 {
    static void visit(Class<?> clazz) {
        Object[] enumConstants = clazz.getEnumConstants();
        if (enumConstants[0] instanceof Children) for (Object o : enumConstants)
            visit((Children) o, clazz.getName());
    }
    static void visit(Children children, String prefix) {
        if (children instanceof Enum) {
            System.out.println(prefix + ' ' + children);
            if (children.children() != null) for (Object o : children.children())
                visit((Children) o, prefix + ' ' + children);
        } else
            System.out.println("other " + children.getClass());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        visit(Thing.animal," ");
        visit(Thing.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From an oops perspective it would be a good idea to break them into cohesive units. So if I were you, I would evaluate which of these enums have a cohesion towards a responsibility.