# Convert string to enum value using reflection, where the enum type can be any of several

Tags: java, reflection, enums

Suppose I have a class that takes another object as an id:

```
public SomeClass
{
    private final ID id;

    ...
}
```

`ID` is then defined as below. Note that the reason that the enum is split up (into logical groupings) is because a single enum would otherwise contain 1000+ values. The interface is then necessary to still have all the enums fall under the same type.

```
public interface ID
{
    public enum Name1 implements ID { ... constants ... }
    public enum Name2 implements ID { ... constants ... }
    public enum Name3 implements ID { ... constants ... }

    ...
}
```

And an object of `SomeClass` is constructed like so:

```
SomeClass object = new SomeClass(ID.Name2.SOME_VALUE, ... more parameters};
```

However, the parameters necessary to construct the `SomeClass` object are stored in a json file, like so:

```
{
    "id": "SOME_VALUE",

    ...
}
```

What I want to do is to map the string `"SOME_VALUE"` to `ID.Name2.SOME_VALUE`. Now, I could do this by having a giant map:

```
Map<String, ID> conversionMap = HashMap<>();
conversionMap.put("SOME_VALUE", ID.Name2.SOME_VALUE);
conversionMap.put("SOME_OTHER_VALUE", ID.Name3.SOME_OTHER_VALUE);
... etc
```

but I want to do it automatically using reflection from a static method inside the `ID` interface (some very rough pseudocode):

```
public interface ID
{
    public static ID getIdFromString(String key)
    {
        List<Enum> declaredEnums = ID.class.getDeclaredEnums();
        for (Enum declaredEnum : declaredEnums)
        {
            for (EnumValue value : declaredEnum)
            {
                if (value.equals(key)
                    return value;
            }
        }
    }

    public enum Name1 implements ID { ... constants ... }
    public enum Name2 implements ID { ... constants ... }
    public enum Name3 implements ID { ... constants ... }

    ...
}
```

How would I do such a thing? I am getting lost in the reflection here, and having searched through many other questions and answers I still seem to not be any closer to the answer.

Note that I could also implement this using 1000+ integer constants and providing a string > integer mapping for that, but using enums feels cleaner. Now that I have hit this snag I am not so convinced of the cleanliness anymore though. It is starting to feel like I am trying to fit a round peg into a square hole.

UPDATE: I ended up using the accepted answer as the solution and modified it a tiny bit to work with my code:

```
public static ID getIdFromString(String key)
{
    Optional<?> id = Arrays.stream(ID.class.getDeclaredClasses())
        .filter(Class::isEnum)
        .flatMap(aClass -> Arrays.stream(aClass.getEnumConstants()))
        .filter(enumValue -> enumValue.toString().equals(key))
        .findFirst();

        return (ID)id.get();
}
```

Beware that this code does not do *any* checking at all, so you should probably add some checks to it to handle invalid keys, and maybe even handle enums that are declared in `ID` but do not implement the `ID` interface.

Comment: Why create multiple enums, instead of just one, especially considering they are nested inside the interface?

Comment: Because when I looked for best practices on large enums in Java I found this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671088/breaking-up-a-large-java-enum.

Comment: Enums are compile-time constants, which means they are mostly useful when code have to refer to them by name. If you have so many enums that you're considering splitting them up, are you really referring to all of them by name in the code? Or are you really only referring to them by string value from e.g. a database? If the latter, then they shouldn't be enums in the first place.

Comment: Yes, each of the values from each of the enums will be referred to at least once somewhere in the code (some will be referred to many times). As I said, I could also be using a class containing all the required string/int constants and a map function mapping the identifier from the json file to the internal string/int constant, but weren't enums designed to avoid having to use these 'normal' constants? Note that I am not directly using the external string identifiers as keys for these objects, because I only want valid identifiers to be used inside the code.

Comment: Your problem seems to be a kind of string-interning problem. So you might be much more efficient by defining `String`-constants and your method `String getIdFromString(String str)` will just delegate to `str.intern()`. The giant map is the jvm string table and lookup is probably more efficient than a custom giant map (yet O(1) but probably higher constant) or reflection (O(n) where n is the number of constants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all declared classes via reflection (including enums) and do something like this:

```
 Arrays.stream(getClass().getDeclaredClasses())
      .filter(Class::isEnum)
      .flatMap(aClass -> Arrays.stream(aClass.getEnumConstants()))
      .filter(enumValue -> enumValue.toString().equals(YOUR_VALUE_FROM_JSON))
      .findFirst();
```

Comment: I (as the programmer) do indeed know which enums are defined in the `ID` interface and could just write loops searching each of those enums in `getIdFromString`, but I do not want to keep adding (or removing) a loop to the `getIdFromString` method each time I add or remove an enum. Using reflection would make this work with an arbitrary amount of declared enums.

Comment: got it. I've updated my answer. tell me if it helped

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this does not seem to return anything, i.e. the Optional it returns is empty (even though the string I passed in exactly matches the name of one of the enums values).

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake in the code. I've updated the answer. Please, try it

Comment: This worked, I can now just retrieve the object from the `Optional` and cast it to `ID`. Thanks again for your help!